# how to get current player rank in openfeint in android app

Tags: android, rank, openfeint

In my android app i m using open feint and i m facing problem in getting my rank(current player).
how do i get that.here is my code.

```
     //hard coded for example
long scoreValue = 60;
    Score s = new Score(scoreValue, null); 
    Leaderboard l = new Leaderboard(String.valueOf(HomeScreen.LeaderBoardId));
    s.submitTo(l, new Score.SubmitToCB() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(boolean newHighScore) {

            System.out.println("Score submitted successfully");

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String exceptionMessage) {
            Toast.makeText(GameScreen.this,
                    "Error (" + exceptionMessage + ") posting score.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
User u= OpenFeint.getCurrentUser();

    int rank=s.rank;
    System.out.println("RANK"+rank);
```

i can get the user details but i dont know how do i get my rank. i m stuck.please help.
thanks in advance.

Comment: int rank=s.rank;
    System.out.println("RANK"+rank);
 always returns zero rank....

Answer (score 0):

Rank is not set when you submit a score. See this discussion for [details](https://ofdev.zendesk.com/entries/20148822-why-current-user-rank-is-always-1).

You have to use the leaderboard to get the rank. 
Also openfient is being replaced with [GREE](http://support.openfeint.com/dev/openfeint-to-gree/), so if you are just starting you may want to switch to the new platform.